# Adding Volumetic to a scene changes the alpha transparency around my vegetation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency, volumetrics

I've imported some vegetation from the "tree vegetation addon"
Here's what it looks like

[image]
When I add a volumetric cube (not to the world), to add some fog, It messes up the transparency layer of the leaves.

[image]
Any idea why ?

My leaf node here:
[image]

My volumetric node here:
[image]

I'm using Blender 2.93 with cycles.

I feel It must be a setting to enable in cycle's render, I'm just not sure which one..
Thanks

[image]

Comment: On the off chance - try increasing volume bounces under *Light Paths*

Comment: @AllenSimpson I've increased it pretty high and still same problem. I'll add a pic in the post

Comment: Thanks.  Tough to say, I can't tell what's going on inside this VEGETATION_LEAF node group.